# Split and join strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string

I have a problem, I have table 'ip_address' with 4 fields:
- id_ip
- client_id
- client_ip
- mac_address

I have added new field named 'router' and I need to fill it up, as I have 800 rows manually will very hard, is it possible to do that in some kind of oneliner from phpMyAdmin?

'router' is generally x.y.z.1 where x.y.z are first octets from field 'client_ip'

Sample row:
1 ; 8001 ; **10.3.8.2** ; 00:00:00:00:00:AA ; 10.3.8.**1**

Comment: you only have mysql or php script will do?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have phpMyAdmin, I can run any python script in case if I got it in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update ip_address
set router = concat(substring_index(client_ip,'.',3), '.1');
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Ok, I understand it will strip my ip address to only 3 first octets, but how to add that .1 on the end?

Comment: That's a useful function `substring_index`, but I think you're looking at an `update` statement and you need to concat on the `.1` at the end as well per the spec.  `update ip_address
set router = concat(substring_index(client_ip,'.',3), '.1');
` See here for example: http://sqlize.com/uRWZ9477B8

Comment: So basically, I can now run it in python loop to update all 800 rows or is there any kind of automation to be used from mysql point of view?

Comment: The query @mellamokb suggested (and edited in the answer) will update all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's SUBSTRING_INDEX function here to get the first 3 octets. This query will populate your new router field by trying to use the first 3 octets from your client_ip field, as you specified, assuming they are separated by '.' characters. You may want to consider IPv6 before you run this, but assuming everything is IPv4, here you go:

you should check that this is getting you what you want:
    SELECT client_ip, SUBSTRING_INDEX(client_ip, '.', 3) FROM `ip_address`

this will update the router field
    UPDATE ip_address SET router = SUBSTRING_INDEX(client_ip, '.', 3)

edit: I'm apparently too slow :) From your comment, simply concat '.1' on the end: UPDATE ip_address SET router = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(client_ip, '.', 3), '.1')